# possibility of a real time turn by turn guidance navigation app using MapQuest on Android?

Tags: android, navigation, mapquest

I would like to create a navigation application, with mapquest sdk for android, that gives real time turn by turn directions using GPS after a route is created, like when you start a navigation on google maps on button press. Is it possible to implement the feature using just the mapquest sdk or would I require any other api.

Say if there was a possibility, then, is there a way to extract that guidance('turn left/right') cue and use it with in the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I'm currently developing my Bachelor Thesis (a mobile navigation service) with the MapQuest API for Android. So as soon as I submitted it I can offer you the source code, too (will be in about a month). However, I can give you some help of course though.

[Here](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/android-maps-api/documentation#routing) is a nice tutorial from MapQuest of how to implement the route functionality. This is not a real time turn by turn guidance but gives you a first impression where to begin!

You can get all instructions from MapQuest [here](https://open.mapquestapi.com/guidance/#maneuvertypes).

If you prefer another API to display the map this is not a problem as the guidance includes all shape points of the route. I chose the MapQuest API for this though as it is a bit easier to display the map for a first glance. However, I recommend you to draw the route yourself on the map though because the implemented method does not always work properly.

Hope I could help you with that and if you are willing to wait a month, I will post here the link to my GitHub repository with the source code.

Best,
Marius

EDIT:

So I submitted my work and can now give you access to my source code. You find my GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/mrunde/Bachelor-Thesis).

I think the function `getGuidance()` in the `NaviActivity` will be a good starting point for your application. It calls the guidance information from MapQuest and converts the information into a JSONObject. The `Route` class then grabs the required information and sorts them in arrays.

I hope that this will help you with your application. For further questions do not hesitate to ask :)

Best,
Marius

Comment: I will start looking up the sample codes and develop simple applications and I think it will be really helpful if u post the code. thanks, btw

Comment: Hi mrunde, have you uploaded your source code on Github. please let me know

Comment: Hi Gokul, yes I just edited my answer so you can get access to my GitHub repository :)

Comment: pluss one for repository link...!